# Dealing with apply functions of xts object in R

Tags: r, time-series, apply, xts, cumsum

I have a sample xts object with the some data:

```
dates <- seq.Date(from = as.Date("2010-01-01", format = "%Y-%m-%d"), 
to = as.Date("2013-12-01", format = "%Y-%m-%d"), by = "month")

sample_data <- cbind(1:length(dates),length(dates):1)

xts_object <- xts(x = sample_data, order.by = dates)
```

I then use apply.yearly on it with the function cumsum:

```
apply.yearly(x = xts_object, FUN = cumsum)
```

The output is a tranposed matrix, which is not what I originally intended it to return.

I would expect the snippet above to return the same output as:

```
rbind(apply(X = xts_object[1:12],MARGIN = 2,FUN = cumsum),
apply(X = xts_object[13:24],MARGIN = 2,FUN = cumsum),
apply(X = xts_object[25:36],MARGIN = 2,FUN = cumsum),
apply(X = xts_object[37:48],MARGIN = 2,FUN = cumsum))
```

The problem with using apply is that it returns a matrix and not an xts object. While I could solve this by using as.xts, I would like to know if there is something I am missing, or if I am using apply.yearly incorrectly. Using pure apply seems to be more prone to difficult to catch errors and bugs.

Comment: `apply` always returns a `matrix` whether you are using `xts` or `data.frame`

Comment: Just use `reclass()` to make it `xts` again: `reclass(apply(X = xts_object,MARGIN = 2,FUN = cumsum), match.to=xts_object)`

Comment: The output of your `apply` call does not reset the cumulative sum each year.  It's the same as just calling `cumsum(xts_object)`.  `apply.yearly` should also reset the cumulative sum each year.

Comment: Well observed Joshua, I've edited the original post but I think everyone got the point. I expected cumsum with apply.yearly to calculate the cumulative sum of each column reseting at the start of a new year. Last but not least, I expected it to return an object with the same format (dimensions and class) as my original xts_object, but with the cumulative sums in each of the columns.

Comment: @Rime Thanks, very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not be the most elegant solution, but it works:

```
# Split xts_object by year
xts_list = split(xts_object, "years")
# cumsum for each year
cumsum_list = lapply(xts_list, FUN = cumsum)
# rbind them together
do.call(rbind, cumsum_list)  

#             [,1] [,2]
# 2010-01-01    1   48
# 2010-02-01    3   95
# 2010-03-01    6  141
# 2010-04-01   10  186
# 2010-05-01   15  230
# 2010-06-01   21  273
# 2010-07-01   28  315
# 2010-08-01   36  356
# 2010-09-01   45  396
# 2010-10-01   55  435
# 2010-11-01   66  473
# 2010-12-01   78  510
# 2011-01-01   13   36
# 2011-02-01   27   71
# 2011-03-01   42  105
# 2011-04-01   58  138
# 2011-05-01   75  170
# 2011-06-01   93  201
# 2011-07-01  112  231
# 2011-08-01  132  260
# 2011-09-01  153  288
# 2011-10-01  175  315
# 2011-11-01  198  341
# 2011-12-01  222  366
# 2012-01-01   25   24
# 2012-02-01   51   47
# 2012-03-01   78   69
# 2012-04-01  106   90
# 2012-05-01  135  110
# 2012-06-01  165  129
# 2012-07-01  196  147
# 2012-08-01  228  164
# 2012-09-01  261  180
# 2012-10-01  295  195
# 2012-11-01  330  209
# 2012-12-01  366  222
# 2013-01-01   37   12
# 2013-02-01   75   23
# 2013-03-01  114   33
# 2013-04-01  154   42
# 2013-05-01  195   50
# 2013-06-01  237   57
# 2013-07-01  280   63
# 2013-08-01  324   68
# 2013-09-01  369   72
# 2013-10-01  415   75
# 2013-11-01  462   77
# 2013-12-01  510   78

class(do.call(rbind, cumsum_list))
# [1] "xts" "zoo"
```

The resulting object would still be "xts"

Comment: Good answer. This is what `apply.yearly` should do. That it doesn't seems like a bug.  I'll have to think about how `period.apply` currently works in order to patch.

Comment: useR this is what I was originally thinking, I edited my original post to reflect what you answered. As Joshua commented this is what apply.yearly should do, so I guess I really wasn't using apply.yearly wrongly and it needs a patch. Thanks both of you!